# Swapping elements in array recursively

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I've been trying to swap elements that i store in array recursively.

My array stores a list of upper and lower case letter using the `rand()` like below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{           
    alphabets[i] = (rand() % 26 + 65 + rand() % 2 * 32);          
}
```

The objective is to swap uppercase and lowercase elements and move all lower case and uppercase to the left and right respectively

Thi function is meant to swaps the element recursively until `(i == j)` condition is met.

```
void swapElementR(char alphabets[], int size)
{
    int temp;
    int i = 0;
    int j = size - 1;

    if(i == j)
    {
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (alphabets[i] >= 'A' && alphabets[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            if (alphabets[j] >= 'a' && alphabets[j] <= 'z')
            {
                temp = alphabets[i];
                alphabets[i] = alphabets[j];
                alphabets[j] = temp;                    
            }
            else
               --j;         
        }
        else
            ++i;                         
    }

    swapElementR(alphabets, --size);
}
```

However, it is returning the same array while only swapping 1 alphabet instead.
I tried to add and minus the first and the last array respectively until it reaches a base case of `i=j` while reducing the size.

Assumingly, the swap works, I call the function and display using my for-loop

```
void moveElementR(char alphabets[], int size)
{

    cout << "Recursive swap of array" << endl;

    swapElementR(alphabets, size);


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << alphabets[i] << "   ";
    }

    return;

}
```

Comment: Show us the call to the recursive function. Note that your `i` and `j` values are identical at start always and aren't passed along.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to post a good question. Have been out from coding and using stackoverflow for 2.5 years after having to serve the military and leaving my programming behind and everything turned rusty :/

Comment: It's still a little hard to tell what you want the function to *do*, exactly. Can you give some desired inputs and outputs?

Comment: I think `swapElementR(alphabets, --size);` changed to `swapElementR(alphabets + i, size - i);` may be a bit closer to what you intended (I'm not claiming it's correct fix, I'm not even sure what is it supposed to do).

Comment: @Ped7g and what if `i` is zero?

Comment: But if this is some practice of recursion, then you should step over it in debugger either way, so you will be able to figure it out on your own then. (otherwise it doesn't make sense, why you would want to use recursion for some swapping of letters in array). @kfsone: it will create infinite cycle for certain inputs.. :)

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan What should your function return for the input `ABcdE`?

Comment: @gsamaras it's mostly passive rep from a popular question and a popular answer from 2013. I don't blame OP overmuch--etiquette here has shifted since he was on here last and as mentioned he's a bit rusty.

Comment: @kfsone the output is suppose to be  `dcBAE`

Comment: @jaggedSpire thank you for your understanding. It's been so long and i do mostly website designs.

Comment: @Ped7g i'm using an IDE quincy that doesn't really have any debugging properties and this recursive swap of letters in array is just a practice on recursion.

Comment: So... switch IDE? Get external debugger? MS VS has now some free editions (I have no idea what they contain, I'm on linux only) Or you may try my favourite [U++ framework+IDE](http://ultimatepp.org/) in combination with Microsoft SDK, it should work quite well for these exercises. Or just add lot of `std::cerr << ... debug info;` lines to your code. Or paper+pen. That last one is maybe even best, for practice, but you still should have some way to verify your way, so again debugger is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted algorithm like this (pseudo C-like language):

```
//input is `array`, `i` (first char index) and `j` (last char index).
void recursion(char array[], int i, int j) {
    if (j <= i) return; // no more chars to process
    if (array[i] in [a-z]) {
        recursion(array, i+1, j); // [i] was already lower case, skip it
        return;
    }
    if (array[j] in [A-Z]) {
        recursion(array, i, j-1); // [j] was already upper case, skip it
        return;
    }
    // here [i] is upper case and [j] is lower case -> swap them
    swap(array[i], array[j]);
    recursion(array, i+1, j-1); // resolve characters between the swapped ones
}

cout << recursion("ABcdE", 0, 4); // should produce "dcBAE"
```

BTW, I forgot to add "return" after the "skip it" parts on my first try, this is so abusive usage of recursion, that I had to check my code twice to catch that. But you should debug your original code, if you want to get less rusty. If you want to stay rusty, hire some programmer.

Comment: Incidentally, if OP just wants a way to stick all their capital letters after all their lowercase letters (or some similar scenario), they might want to have a look at [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)

Comment: @jaggedSpire yes. But if he wants to practice programming skills, he should reinvent the wheel quite often. The same goes for `std::swap`. Although reimplementing `isupper` for UTF-8 may be instructive anecdote and life time experience, how "should be simple" things turn into disaster fast... :D

Comment: I mostly figured OP might not know about the wonders of <algorithm>, and exactly [how useful it can be](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f971696437381bc)

Comment: @Ped7g without the size of my array, how am i suppose to allow `j` to be the last element of the array? In my codes, i have to initialize j as the last element by letting `int j = size - 1` while `int i = 0` for the first element

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan: question is, why do you calculate first and last element of array inside your recursion. That's quite anti-recursion pattern. Check my answer again, I calculate first and last element once, upon initial call of "recursion()". Inside it I simply operate on the range "from i, to j", those being the local first/last element for particular level of recursion. That's common theme of recursive algorithms, you get some partial state of calculation, and you continue in it on "deeper level" (in my answer further narrowing i,j, until they meet).

Comment: "calculate" = the sample call `recursion("ABcdE", 0, 4);` (first/last element indices hardcoded)

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan: My "partial state of calculation" are parameters: `array` (in C++ it would made sense to make it member variable of class, not putting pointer on stack each call) and local first/last element index (`i`/`j`). From that I can either terminate calculation (last <= first), or narrow it down either by skipping first/last characters - when they fulfil the condition, or by swapping first<->last, and continue with calculation on the inner part between. Notice how recursion sort-of doesn't care about count of swaps or size of array. Simple logic will still do it.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan: You just have to make sure during recursion algorithm design, that by every deeper call to yourself you inevitably progress toward terminating condition. In this example case a call `recursion(array, i, j)` inside would feel wrong (giving the deeper call probably the same partial calculation state, risking infinite cycle), or any opposite movement of `i`/`j` would signalize something's probably not right, or too complex.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan: Funny coincidence: in the example the call after swap with `i+1`, `j-1` **can** be replaced by the "wrong" i,j - would cause just few more wasted deeper calls, but it would work, as `array` did change, so the partial state of calculation is different after swap.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input `ABcdE` your code will start with

```
i=0, j=(5-1)=4
alphabets[i]=A, alphabets[j]=E
[j] (E) is uppercase => no swap
i++ = 1 (i is not used again)
swapElementR(alphabets, 4)
    i=0, j=(4-1)=3
    alphabets[i]=A, alphabets[j]=d
    swap => dBcAE
    i++ = 1 (i is not used again)
    swapElementR(alphabets, 3)
        i=0, j=(3-1)=2
        alphabets[i]=d, alphabets[j]=c
        [i] (d) is lowercase => no swap
```

as of this point, because `alphabets[0]` is lowercase, and `i` is always set to `0` at the start of each iteration, no further swaps can occur.

In order to do this properly, you will need a function that considers both the left and right positions to work from:

```
void swapElementR(char* alphabets, int begin, int end)
```

Here I'm using the idiomatic naming convention for iterators, where `end` is past the last element, so it lines up with your use of size in the original.

I would also encourage you to consider using `std::swap` instead of writing your own `swap` code

```
std::swap(alphabets[i], alphabets[j])
```

and use `isupper` and `islower` from `<cctype>`

```
#include <cctype>
...
if (isupper(alphabets[i]) && islower(alphabets[j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're set on a recursive solution. Just in case an iterative solution could help:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void partition(vector<char>& chracters) {
  int i = 0, j = chracters.size() - 1;
  while (i < j) {
    while (islower(chracters[i]) && i < j) i++;
    while (isupper(chracters[j]) && j > i) j--;
    swap(chracters[i], chracters[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I managed to do a swap iteratively with a loop which is rather straight forward. however I'm trying to practice and understand the recursive logic for swapping this letters

Comment: but I'm stuck for ages trying to figure it out

Comment: When learning recursion, drawing a tree with the recursive states was very helpful. The states in the tree should be the expected/correct states. Once you have that, run your algorithm one step at time and verify that the states you see in the debugger/console/etc match those in your tree. It's a tedious exercise, but it should help. Bonus: it will make you appreciate iterative solutions even more :-)

Comment: of course I appreciate iterative solution more but somehow recursive practice are needed. that is why I'm trying to find a solution to solve this problem using the recursive method